# Removing password/session settings from profiles to allow org defaults to apply to all users

Tags: profile, security, session, passwords

Has anyone managed to remove profile session/password settings to allow the org defaults to apply to all users? Can't seem to remove session timeout to "none" on the profile UI, it only allows you to choose a timeout option, as per the screenshot below.

[image]

According to documentation here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_session.htm&type=0 
"You can control session settings on a user profile basis. If you don’t configure the profile session settings, the org’s session settings apply to users of the profile. When set, the profile settings override the org-wide settings."

Has anyone removed the profile settings to allow the org-wide settings to apply?

Currently investigating using Metadata API:

ProfileSessionSettings on Metadata API:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilesessionsetting.htm#meta_profilesessionsetting

Update: It seems ProfileSessionSettings are not easily deployable between environments, as they are created automatically with a different name in each org (e.g. My_Custom_Profile_profileSessionSetting1530713097465.profileSessionSetting), and only one of these files can exist per Profile name - otherwise, a deployment error occurs. Could be possible to set these on first deployment of a new profile to an org, but for an existing project, moving users off profiles to destroy and redeploy them can be quite time-consuming.

ProfilePasswordPolicy on Metadata API:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm#meta_profilepasswordpolicy

SecuritySettings on Metadata API:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm

Comment: Can you clarify a bit as what are you trying? If the profiles don't have a session setting set specifically on profiles, then its always the Org Wide setting that applies to all profiles.

Comment: Sure @JayantDas, have added a screenshot - I'm trying to remove the session settings from the profile to allow the Org Wide setting to apply.

Comment: Hi @AislinnHayes were you able to remove them?

Comment: I don't believe so no! But this was a long time ago and I don't work on that project anymore - apologies!

Answer (score 0):

As for your question:

> Has anyone removed the profile settings to allow the org-wide settings to apply?

You don't really need to remove the session settings from the profile. If you haven't explicitly made any changes on the profile level, by default a profile's session settings inherits what is configured Org Wide.

E.g., the default session timeout is 2 hours. If you haven't made any change at Org or Profile level, and if you verify it on every profile, you will see 2 hours in there.

Now, if at all you have changed anything on the profile, that then classifies as an override on Org Wide.

Comment: Is there any way to reverse a change on the profile level once it's been made? And does this apply for deploying custom profiles via Metadata API?

Comment: I haven’t tried it out but I would think Yes. Just by looking at the [metadata api docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilesessionsetting.htm) for session settings for profiles, it looks it can be done.